# Convert piglatin to english?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I made a simple program to convert English to PigLatin. But now I'm stuck as to how to convert it back to English. Here is an example of English to PigLatin:

**input**
    hello world this is great

**output**

```
elloXhaWEY orldXwWEY isXthWEY isWAY eatXgrWEY
```

So, the rules are:
1. If word starts with vowel, it ends with WAY(e.g eal -> ealWAY)
2. If word starts with consonant, it keeps checking for as long as a consonant is present, strips the first part and then convert it. (e.g This -> isXthWEY) Notice the X before the stripped letters and WEY after them.

I managed to make a program to convert them to that. But how can I convert from the messed up letters back to English?

My idea is to check each word from the end. If it ends with WEY, I strip ou the last 3 words, grab the letters from the last till it reaches X and then strip X and then move the words to the beginning. But I'm lost on how to do it.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, you've even tried? You asked the opposite just an hour ago or so. We don't do homeworks.

Comment: Your question is full of contradictions: "X-WEY" in text, but "X-WAY" in output, "elloXhaWAY" with an extra "a", etc.

Comment: I tried it. But it doesn't work.

Comment: @Hyperboreus Edited it. Still I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
def decode (line):
    return ' '.join (token [:-3]
        if token.endswith ('WAY')
        else (lambda a, b: b [:-3] + a) (*token.split ('X') )
        for token in line.split () )
```

Sample:

```
>>> decode ('elloXHWEY orldXwWEY isXthWEY isWAY eatXgrWEY')
'Hello world this is great'
```

Nota bene: Might fail with words conaining 'X'. But it should be something to get you started.

Comment: I managed to get it work with a longer process. token is something new to me and your answer is really elegant compared to mine. I'll  keep this in mind. Thanks

Comment: @Sab Gald to help. `token` is just a variable name. You can also call it `x`, `strawberry` or `Sab`.